# 'dx' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, command-line

I want make dex file from jar file with command-line. I use the command mentioned bellow:

```
dx --dex --output="c:\temp\dx.dex" "c:\temp\in.jar"
```

I got the error " 'dx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

How I can fix it?

Thank You

Comment: Have you added the folder containing dx to your path?

Comment: No, how should i add that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add android build-tools to your path (or always operate in the correct directory, but I wouldn't recommend that).

How to add something to the path: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

In this case you have to add `%YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_LOCATION%\build-tools\%CURRENT_VERSION%`. (For example `C:\Program Files\Android\SDK\build-tools\23.0.2`)